# Rearranging CSV rows to match another CSV based on data in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering if there is a fast way to rearrange the rows of a csv using pandas so that it could match the order of the rows in another csv that have the same data, but arranged differently. To be clear, these two csvs have the same data in the form of several numeric features spread across several columns. I tried doing loops that matches each row of data with its counterpart by comparing the values in multiple columns, but this prove too slow for my purposes.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example? What about using the `sort_values` method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas DataFrame:

1. "read_csv"__both files.
2. Convert both to "DataFrame".
3. Use "merge".
4. "to_csv"__use to save.

share your data..